# Kafka Consumer: can onPartitionsRevoked and onPartitionsAssigned callbacks be executed inside one poll() call?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using kafka consumer api 0.10.2.1.

KafkaConsumer provides a callback for partition assignment and revoking:

```
consumer.subscribe(topics, consumerRebalanceListener);
```

Where `consumerRebalanceListener` has two methods:

```
public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions);
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions);
```

As everything in Kafka consumer happens in single thread, and inside poll() method, these callbacks are called from inside `poll()` method. 
The question is, can they both be called from one `poll()` call or they always require two separate `poll()` calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, they are called from on `poll()` call. When a consumer instance starts to join the group, `onPartitionsRevoked` is firstly invoked to revoke all the partitions assigned to this instance and sends the JoinGroup request. Then it blocks indefinitely until the response is received. If it joins group successfully, it executes user's callback by calling `onPartitionsAssigned`. All of these are finished in one single round of `poll`.

Comment: Thanks, I assume it is expected behaviour you saw before or what you understood from code. Is it also documented somewhere?